# Samsung Galaxy Note Edge 5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

The phone randomly shuts off when it gets around 30% power.  Verizon says it's a software issue.  Thoughts or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's a software issue. Any guarantee? It's also worth to try a factory reset and a new battery. If that does not help, go to a mobile repair service. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, try using some system utility apps for the battery and/or hardware to check if everything is sound. Also, trying to contact Samsung won't hurt if the phone is still under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your phone's software measures battery's charge level incorrectly. You can fix that with factory reset or use some apps for fixing that if you have root.